# RxJava alternative of group by in sql

Tags: reactive-programming, java-7, rx-java2

I have a list of `Student`:

```
Observable<Student> source = Observable.fromIterable(getStudentList());
```

I would like to group them by postal code, along with how many times they appear, but the problem is that I use java 7

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy`, `flatMap` and `count` on the groups themselves:

```java
source.groupBy(s -> s.postalCode)
.flatMapSingle(g -> 
    g.count()
    .map(v -> g.getKey() + ": " + v))
;
```

Without lambdas it looks more ugly though:

```
source.groupBy(new Function<Student, String>() {
    @Override public String apply(Student s) {
        return s.postalCode;
    }
})
.flatMapSingle(new Function<GroupedObservable<String, Student>, Single<String>>() {
    @Override public String apply(final GroupedObservable<String, Student> group) {
        return group.count().map(new Function<Long, String>() {
            @Override public String apply(Long count) {
                 return group.getKey() + ": " + count;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: after that i must implement subscribe?

Comment: Actually, you could keep it as is because it is such a beauty on itself and StackOverflow doesn't allow me to comment just "yes".

Comment: it dosnt work,
its underlined by red in my intelliJ,
Incompatible type:
required :java.lang.string
found:io.reactivex.single

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: i have another question
if i want to access to the list of student for postal code 900 and i want to modify for example the name of each student
how to do that?
thanks

Comment: That's a completely different flow and question.