# RXjava alternative of group by

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, java-7

i have a student class that contain lastname,firstname,postalCode and distance
i want to group student by postalCode and show the distance (sum of distance by postal code)

For example postalCode 900 :student a,student b,student c,sum =500

the problem is that im using java 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368164/rxjava-alternative-of-group-by-in-sql

Comment: that's a different question

Comment: You say "i want to group student by postalCode" vs ["I would like to group them by postal code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368164/rxjava-alternative-of-group-by-in-sql). Also what is the question or problem you are actually facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RXjava alternative of group by in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368164/rxjava-alternative-of-group-by-in-sql)